# Unity GUI not in build, but works fine in editor

Tags: c#, unity, gui

I have:

1. GUITexture attached to an object
2. A script that has GUIStyles created for the Textfield and Buttons that are created in OnGUI(). This script is attached to the same object in number 1
3. 3 GUIText objects each separate from the above.
4. A script that enables the GUITexture and the script in number 1 and 2 respectively

This is how it is supposed to work:
When I cross the finish line, number 4 script enables number 1 GUITexture component and number 2 script component. The script component uses one of number 3's GUIText objects to show you your best lap time, and also makes a GUI.Textfield for name entry and 2 GUI.Buttons for "Submit" and "Skip". If you hit "Submit" the script will submit the time. No matter which button you press, The remaining 2 GUIText objects from number 3 will show you the top 10 best times.

For some reason, when I run it in editor, everything works 100%, but when I'm in different kinds of builds, the results vary.

When I am in a webplayer, The GUITexture and the textfield and buttons appear, but the textfield and buttons are plain and have no evidence of GUIStyles. When I click one of the buttons, the score gets submitted but I do not get the fastest times showing.

When I am in a standalone build, the GUITexture shows up, but nothing else does. If I remove the GUIStyle parameter of the GUI.Textfield and GUI.Button, they show up.

Why am I getting these variations and how can I fix it?

Code below:

```
    void  Start ()
    {
        Names.text = "";
        Times.text = "";
        YourBestTime.text = "Your Best Lap: " + bestTime + "\nEnter your name:";

        //StartCoroutine(GetTimes("Test"));

    }

void Update()
{
    if (!ShowButtons && !GettingTimes)
    {
        StartCoroutine(GetTimes());
        GettingTimes = true;
    }
}

IEnumerator GetTimes ()
{   
    Debug.Log("Getting times");
    YourBestTime.text = "Loading Best Lap Times";
    WWW times_get = new WWW(GetTimesUrl);
    yield return times_get;
    WWW names_get = new WWW(GetNamesUrl);
    yield return names_get;

    if(times_get.error != null || names_get.error != null) 
    {
        print("There was an error retrieiving the data: " + names_get.error + times_get.error);
    } 
    else 
    {
        Times.text = times_get.text;
        Names.text = names_get.text;
        YourBestTime.text = "Your Best Lap: " + bestTime;
    }    
}

IEnumerator PostLapTime (string Name, string LapTime)
{
    string hash= MD5.Md5Sum(Name + LapTime + secretKey); 
    string bestTime_url = SubmitTimeUrl + "&Name=" + WWW.EscapeURL(Name) + "&LapTime=" + LapTime + "&hash=" + hash;

    Debug.Log (bestTime_url);
    // Post the URL to the site and create a download object to get the result.
    WWW hs_post = new WWW(bestTime_url);
    //label = "Submitting...";
    yield return hs_post; // Wait until the download is done
    if (hs_post.error != null) 
    {
        print("There was an error posting the lap time: " + hs_post.error);
        //label = "Error: " + hs_post.error;
        //show = false;
    }
    else
    {
        Debug.Log("Posted: " + hs_post.text);       
        ShowButtons = false;
        PostingTime = false;
    }
}

void OnGUI()
{
    if (ShowButtons)
    {
        //makes text box            
        nameString = GUI.TextField( new Rect((Screen.width/2)-111, (Screen.height/2)-130, 222, 25), nameString, 20, TextboxStyle);

        if (GUI.Button( new Rect( (Screen.width/2-74.0f), (Screen.height/2)- 90, 64, 32), "Submit", ButtonStyle))
        {
            //SUBMIT TIME
            if (nameString == "")
            {
                nameString = "Player";
            }
            if (!PostingTime)
            {
                StartCoroutine(PostLapTime(nameString, bestTime));
                PostingTime = true;
            }

        }
        else if (GUI.Button( new Rect( (Screen.width/2+10.0f), (Screen.height/2)- 90, 64, 32), "Skip", ButtonStyle))
        {
            ShowButtons = false;
        }
    }
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it wasn't working was because I had C# and Javascript scripts with the same class name.